# Resources$NotFoundException after updating android studio to 3.3.2

Tags: android

So I am facing this problem after I updated Android Studio to 3.3.2 version. Till then everything was working fine and never did I faced this issue before. An xml image is stored in drawable folder. This is used in materialintro.slide.SimpleSlide. I checked for solutions but nothing worked. I have already added

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

The app crashes mostly below Android 6 version devices. Any help is appreciated.

AppIntroActivity:

```
public class AppIntroActivity extends IntroActivity {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_INTRO = 1;
    static
    {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setFullscreen(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addSlide(new SimpleSlide.Builder()

                .title("Welcome to NotEfi")
                .description("All college related information customized at one place")
                .image(R.drawable.ic_icons8_box)  //error in this line
                .background(R.color.blackPrimary)
                .layout(R.layout.splash_intro)
                .backgroundDark(R.color.colorAccent)
                .scrollable(false)
                .build());

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_icons8_document.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800a7
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3453)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1896)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(Unknown Source)
       at studentapp.notefi.Gridshow$GridAdapter.getView(Unknown Source)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2351)
       at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1356)
       at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
       at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
       at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:421)
       at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1244)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2207)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(Unknown Source)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1692)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1534)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1443)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15033)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4799)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5996)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: You can try to change `compileSdkVersion` to 24 and bump version all of the libraries to `24.X.X`

Comment: @Boken I am using `compileSdkVersion` 27

Comment: I'm facing similar issues. App runs fine when build from android studio 3.2.1 but crash when run from 3.3.2

Comment: it seems android studio 3.3.2 is not generating png images from svg on lower device.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've put your `ic_icons8_box` icon in drawable-v24 folder try putting it in normal drawable folder.

Comment: I found no such folder.